# How to configure this code as spring Bean?

Tags: hibernate, spring, configuration, javabeans, sessionfactory

I have this code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

How i may to configure this as bean?
hibernate.cfg.xml contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="sessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">scott</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x:1521:x</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">scott</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">SCOTT</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        <mapping resource="ormbyxml/domain/Emp.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ormbyxml/domain/SalaryLog.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ormbyxml/domain/Dept.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ormbyxml/domain/Salgrade.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ormbyxml/domain/Bonus.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Your code does not compile...

Comment: O_o it's part of hibernate configuration, i want translate this to spring bean configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, of course, explained in the Spring reference documentation. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup.

You may pass the path of your hibernate config file like this:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you for replay, I wont use org.hibernate.SessionFactory and org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration objects.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, then. The link I gave you explains how to be able to configure a Hibernate SessionFactory using Spring. Using this allows you to inject/autowire a SessionFactory in your other Spring beans. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html for the other properties you can pass to the bean. What's explained in the spring doc corresponds to what you asked: it configures a SessionFactory and makes it available as a Spring bean.

Comment: The link explains how to configure a Hibernate SessionFactory using by org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean and org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource classes.
I just want to translate my code to the spring configuration.
My code use org.hibernate.SessionFactory and org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: So what? LocalSessionFactoryBean is a FactoryBean<org.hibernate.SessionFactory>. This means it provides access to a SessionFactory. What do you want? Why does this solution, which is the one documented by Spring, doesn't fit you?

Comment: Sorry, I edit question. My hibernate.cfg.xml not compatible with LocalSessionFactoryBean, and I don't can edit this config.

Comment: Of course it's compatible. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setConfigLocation%28org.springframework.core.io.Resource%29 and my edited answer